Alternate proof to "$f(x)$ is bounded if each $f_n(x)$ is bounded"
The question is as follows: Suppose that $(f_n)$ converges to a function $f$ uniformly on $D$. Prove that if each $f_n$ is bounded on $D$ then $f$ is bounded on $D$. Prove also that there is a uniform hound for the $f_n$, i.e. there exists $K \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$|f_n(x)|\leq K$ for all $x \in D$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
My solution is: If $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $D$, then there exists an $M_n = \text{sup}|f_n - f|$ for all $x \in D$ such that $M_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Since each $f_n$ is bounded, then $|f_n(x)|\leq K_n$ for some $K_n \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $x \in D$. Take $K = \text{max}\{K_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Then, given a sufficiently large $N \in \mathbb{N}$, it must be the case that $f_N(x) \leq f(x) \leq K$ for all $x \in D$. Hence $f$ is bounded. Furthermore, $K$ is a uniform bound.
This same question has been asked in here. However, the solution is different than mine. I feel like I may be missing a step somewhere around my statement that $f_N(x) \leq f(x) \leq K$, but I am not too sure what I could add. Is my proof correct? Any feedback is appreciated!

That statement cannot be proved, since it is false.

Do you mean that uniform convergence does not imply the existence of $M_n$? If so, is there a counter-example for such?

@enfield: The uniform convergence is enough here. The problem in you demonstration is IMHO $K = \text{max}{K_n : n \in \mathbb{N}}$. You never explain why $K$ has a finite value. BTW using mainly English text is dangerous: in math expressions the order of quantifiers ($\forall$ and $\exists$) is always explicit while it can be ambiguous in natural language...

You cannot deduce that there is a common bound for all $f_n$'s.

@JoséCarlosSantos: the uniform convergence implies that $f$ is bounded, and that all $f_n$ share a common bound (and the greatest of both is indeed a common bound for everything). Only with simple (non uniform) convergence it is impossible to conclude anything.

@SergeBallesta That is false. Take $D=\Bbb R$,$f_1(x)=x$, $f_n(x)=0$ for each $n>1$ and $f(x)=0$. Then $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly to $f$. Care to tell me which common bound is shared by all $f_n$'s?

@JoséCarlosSantos: The hypothesis is that every $f_n$ is bounded. Your $f_1$ is trivially not.

@SergeBallesta Right. I missed that hypothesis.

Assume $f_n$ is convergent uniformly. In particular $f_n$ satisfies the Cauchy condition. Hence there is $N$ such that
$$|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<1 \quad n,m\ge N$$
In particular $$|f_n(x)-f_N(x)|<1, \ n\ge N \ (*)$$ The latter implies that $f_n$ are uniformly bounded for $n\ge N,$ as $f_N$ is bounded. Thus $f_n$ are uniformly bounded for all $n$ as $f_k$ are bounded for $1\le k\le N.$ By taking the limit in $(*)$ we get
$$|f(x)-f_N(x)|\le 1$$ Thus $f$ is bounded as well.

$$|f(x)|\leq|f(x)-f_N(x)|+|f_N(x)|\leq1+\sup_{x\in D}|f_N(x)|,\quad x\in D.$$

@Riemann You are right. The uniform bound has been discussed in the comments. That's why my answer adresses that issue.

@    Ryszard Szwarc You give a nice answer!

@RyszardSzwarc thank you for your answer! I was also looking for a proof using Cauchy convergence, so this is useful. When it comes to my solution, do you think my it makes sense? Is there some indiscrepancy between my statements?

I went through your solution. You should justify that $K<\infty.$ This can be derived from $M_n\to 0.$

I shall try to give a detailed explaination here.
Hypotheses:

A sequence of functions $(f_n), n\in\Bbb N$ converges uniformly to a function $f$ on a domain $D$: $$\begin{equation}\tag{1}\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists N\in\Bbb N, \forall x\in D, n>N\implies \lvert f(x)-f_n(x)\rvert <\varepsilon\end{equation}$$

Each $f_n$ function is bounded on $D$: $$\tag{2}\forall n \in \Bbb N, \exists K_n, \forall x \in D, \lvert f_n(x)\rvert < K_n$$



We can show that $f$ is bounded:
Let us considere an arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$. Per $(1)$ we can find $N\in\Bbb N$ veryfying $\forall n>N, \forall x\in D, \lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert<\varepsilon$. Particurlarly we can take $N_1 = N+1$ and have $\tag{3}\forall x\in D, \lvert f_{N_1}(x) -f(x)\rvert <\varepsilon$
Per $(2)$, we know that we can find $K_{N_1}$ verifying $$\tag{4}\forall x\in D, \lvert f_{N_1}(x)\rvert < K_{N_1}$$
From $(3)$ and $(4)$ we can deduce immediately $$\forall x\in D, -K_{N_1} -\varepsilon<f_{N_1}(x)-\varepsilon<f(x)<f_{N_1}(x)+\varepsilon<K_{N_1} +\varepsilon \\ \forall x\in D, -K_{N_1} -\varepsilon<f(x)<K_{N_1} +\varepsilon$$
$$\tag5 \forall x\in D,\lvert f(x)\rvert < K_{N_1} +\varepsilon$$
So we have successfully shown that $f$ is bounded.

Let us now show that $(f_n), n\in\Bbb N$ is uniformly bounded.
Per $(1)$ and $(3)$ we have:$$\forall n \ge N_1, \forall x\in D, \lvert f(x) - f_n(x)\rvert < \varepsilon$$
Using $(5)$ and the same method as is above paragraph, we can conclude
$$\tag6 \forall n \ge N_1, \forall x\in D, \lvert f_n(x)\rvert < K_{N_1} +2\varepsilon$$
Using the $(K_n), n\in N$ sequence defined at $(2)$, the set$\{K_n, n<N_1\}$ is finite. That is enough to say that $K=\max(K_{N_1}+2\varepsilon, \{K_n, n<N_1\})$ is a finite real number verifying
$$\forall n\in\Bbb n, \forall x\in D,\left\lbrace\begin{align}\lvert f(x) \rvert < K\\\lvert f_n(x) \rvert < K\end{align}\right.$$
Said differently, we have proved that $f$ funciont is bounded and that the $f_n, n\in\Bbb n$ sequence of functions is uniformly bounded on $D$. ($Q.E.D.$)
